# R: data.table condition and delete columns "NA"

Tags: r

I'm trying to identify lines with a missing date between two dates.

data.table initial
[image]

i want

[image]

I want to delete the columns with only "NA" in them (dt_7 and dt_8).

Comment: Why not removing dt_5? Why are `dt_1`, `dt_2` and `dt_4` NA in line 1? I don't understand your desired output.

Comment: sorry, I edited the wrong output file ;)

I just published the desired output

the purpose is to indicate to the person entering the missing data

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for something like

```r
df <- data.frame(dt_1 = 1:10, dt_2 = c(1, NA, 2, 3, NA, 6:10), dt_3 = rep(NA, 10))

df[,-(which(colSums(is.na(df))==dim(df)[1]))]
```

or

```r
df %>% select_if(colSums(is.na(.))!=dim(df)[1])
```

The first option doesn't work for data.tables. Sorry, but the second one should solve your problem.

Comment: thank you +++ for the first question identify the lines where the date is missing between date, do you have a solution?

Comment: Is this a new question? In this case consider asking a new question for better visibility. Actually I need more explanation what you are trying to do. :-)

Comment: ok I'm going to post a new question, I want to identify if a date is missing between date 

ex: 2020-03-02 NA 2020-04-04